# Save output from terminal to file

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have this command which is being executed on a remote server. I tried to send it to a file on the server that is calling the ssh command but it doesn't look like it is working.

```
ssh $SERVER "su $ORACLE_USER -c 'export ORACLE_HOME=\"/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0\";
                                 export PATH=\"/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/Opatch:\$PATH\";
                                 opatch lsiinventory'" > /tmp/output.txt
```

How can I get it working?

Comment: What happens if you move your last double quote to the very end to also contain the pipe to file command?

Comment: That drops the file and output to the remote server. The output is there though. I would like to have it output to the server that is making the call.

Answer (score 1):

If I place a `()` in the beginning and end of this it works.

```
(ssh $SERVER "su $ORACLE_USER -c 'export ORACLE_HOME=\"/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0\"; export PATH=\"/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/Opatch:\$PATH\"; opatch lsiinventory'") > /tmp/output.txt
```